# Characterset conversion when using Galera Cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

We need to change character set from utf8 to utf8mb4 on MariaDB Galera Cluster.

Can we use wsrep_OSU_method=RSU (rolling schema upgrade) to convert character set.

Online schema change tools are not an option.

What problems can we expect with RSU method?

Thanks

Comment: In order to answer your question, please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `ALTER`, at least for the most complex case.  Possible complexities:  changing from `VARCHAR(255)` to `VARCHAR(191)`, `UNIQUE` or `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, etc.  Also, provide the version number of MariaDB: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';`

Comment: This is MariaDB Galera Cluster 10.2.24. Plan is to test conversion and fix problems with key lengths or data types before going to production to avoid possible errors. We have tables with several FOREIGN KEY's per table and also TRIGGERS which is the reason why online schema tools are not an option.

Comment: Can we convert character sets with ALTER table using RSU method? I am curios if anyone converted character set of the database using RSU method. Thanks

Comment: Alter one node; test things; if something goes wrong, blow away that node and let Galera rebuild it.

Comment: Do you know if anyone has done character set conversion using RSU method on production? We will definitely perform few tests before going to production. Thanks for your help.